# Edit registry without administrator permission

Tags: windows, administrator, regedit, register

I need to do an ADO query from Excel using ADODB. Connection with several types of data. The problem is that in some cases some of the result's recordset have the values empty or numerical. As this connection with ADO automatically detects the type of the fields using only the first 8 recordsets, the query sometimes fails.

Searching on stackoverflow I found one solution, but it implies to edit the registry, but I am not administrator user of the computer.

Se next link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46174530/7787606

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Access
```

Is there any way of modifying that key value without Administrator Permission?

Comment: You do not need permissions if you want to write to Current User. The other keys do require administrative privileges. If you know the exact key, you can open regedit as Administrator, navigate to that key, right-click it, select permissions, and give yourself write permissions.

Comment: @LPChip the thing is that the key is tinto Local Machine

Comment: And this is for doing it on the office's computer, so I don't think they would give me access to restricted keys

Comment: @Joracosu - If the key is in the HKLM root, then the only way to have write permissions is for you to have Administrator permissions

Comment: Ask the IT department to grand you rights to just that sub key. It is really easy to do and will allow you to do your work without actually requiring to be an Administrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

If you are trying to write to any registry keys besides HKEY CURRENT USER you must have local administrator rights.

There is no way around this.